# Basic app that counter++ when the user is sliding

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Firstly, I'm crap at english, I hope you'll understand everything.

I'm trying to create a quick android app that increment (counter++) a variable "counter" each time the user is sliding on the app. It's something really basic, so the code is quite raw.

How it works: I tried to call my "swipe" class in my onCreate activity; a slide is adding +1 to the variable "compteur" and then display it by setting the text on the main screen.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.slideandcount;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

int compteur = 0;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 5;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 125000;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 1;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY_Y = 1;

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
TextView text1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    text1.setText("Debug 1");
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
    text1.setText("Debug 2");
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            text1.setText("Debug3");
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };

}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        text1.setText("fils de pute");
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                text1.setText(String.valueOf(++compteur));
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                text1.setText(String.valueOf(++compteur));
            } else if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY_Y) {
                text1.setText(String.valueOf(++compteur));
            } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY_Y) {
                text1.setText(String.valueOf(++compteur));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.brosselesdentsbatards.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

The interesting thing is, in the "onCreate" activity, I can go to the debug line "debug 2" but I can't go to "debug 3", so I guess the problem is here. But I can't find how to fix it.

Do you have any idea of to fix this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: why are you expecting it should print debug 3? your gestureListener is attached to anything

Comment: Can you show us your logcat?

Comment: what is the expected o/p ?

Comment: what does "o/p" mean? Output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:Syntax**

First add an id to your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.brosselesdentsbatards.MainActivity" 

android:id="@+id/layout">

<TextView ...
```

Then in you onCreate method:

```
RelativeLayout rLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

rLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        text1.setText("Debug3");
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I modified your line "};)" because it said it was a syntax error, I modified with "});".
I'm gonna test it now.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!!
If you have the time, could you explain to me what the layout was for? I'm interested.

Comment: In your code you added the onTouchListener to nothing attached to your views. I just took your layout and add the listener to it

Comment: see the line `gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){...`, you just created a listener but it wasn't attached to anything on your layout